# Duration of stay when using a multiple-entry Schengen visa in Albania

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, croatia, albania, moroccan-citizens

I hold a multiple entry Schengen visa valid for a month, with a duration of stay of 18 days. My first country of entry will be Croatia. Afterwards, I will be using the same visa (waiver system) to visit Bosnia, Montenegro, and Albania. I'll be spending a total of 5 days in Croatia and intend to take my flight back home to Morocco from Albania. Can I stay in Albania for what's left in my stay, which may go beyond 18 days, but with only 5 of those days spent in Croatia and the Schengen area?

Comment: AFAIK a multiple entry visa is valid for 18 days from the date of first entry, not the sum of the days actually spent in the country(ies).

Comment: My question has been edited. The 18 days are actually the duration of stay. Thanks you 

Comment: It's a good question. [This page](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/) says "if you have a valid Schengen visa you can enter Albania visa-free for 90 days" but nothing about what happens if the Schengen visa is valid for less than 90 days. Perhaps they just say "you're good" and stamp the passport with 90 days. As a UK citizen when I visit countries where I don't need a visa *in advance* to enter, they still stamp the passport with xx days validity.

Comment: So the 18 days duration will not apply to Albania?

Comment: Perhaps you need wait for an answer for someone who has done what you propose. It seems to me that having the Shengen visa just means you don't need a formal visa, otherwise the same.